# Set values in multifields elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following structure recorded in elastic:

```
    PUT /movies
{
  "mappings": {
    "title": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { 
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "de": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "german"
            },
            "en": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "fr": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "french"
            },
            "es": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "spanish"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to record values like this:

```
PUT movies/_doc/2
{
  "title": "fox",
  "field": "en"
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [movies] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, title]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [movies] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, title]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong since I am fairly new to elastic. My idea is to create one to one mapping and when I am searching for Fox in any of these languages to return results only in english since they are recorded in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping indicates a mapping type "title" but when you create the documents you use `PUT movies/_doc/2` that indicates mapping type `_doc` which doesn't exist so ES will try to automatically create it, and in newer version of ES having multiple mapping types is forbidden.

You should just change it to: `PUT movies/title/2`